# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied. Using graph-tool on Python

Tags: python, docker, permission-denied, graph-tool

I have taken a look at the similar questions posted on this topic, but unfortunately I have not been able to use previous responses to solve my particular problem.

What I am trying to do is use a Python package by the name of "graph-tool" on my Mac (have also tried this on my Windows machine) through the use of Docker. I will write out specifically what I have tried, but I have just been following the instructions on https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/-/wikis/installation-instructions#installing-using-docker .

First, I run the following line on my terminal 
`docker run -it -u user -w /Users/orlandoferrer/Downloads/pythonstuff tiagopeixoto/graph-tool ipython`

From my understanding, this opens up Python and sets my directory to /Users/orlandoferrer/Downloads/pythonstuff. Next, I run the line `from graph_tool.all import *` to load up the "graph-tool" package I want to use. The next series of lines serve the purpose of creating a simple two-node graph.

```
g=Graph()
v1 = g.add_vertex()
v2=g.add_vertex()
e=g.add_edge(v1, v2)
graph_draw(g, vertex_text=g.vertex_index, output="two-nodes.pdf")
```

Every line before the last one runs just fine, but after running the last line I get the error message `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'two-nodes.pdf'`. My best guess at what's happening is that somehow I don't have permission to create pdf files in the folder I specified. But I already tried going into the folder sharing options and made it so that "everyone" could read/write files in there. I even did the same thing for "Downloads" just to see if that would work, but I keep getting the same error message. I've been at this for two days now, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you running your program ? Using `python myscript.py` ?

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, I'm opening up Python via the line `docker run -it -u user -w /Users/orlandoferrer/Downloads/pythonstuff tiagopeixoto/graph-tool ipython`.